# Prove $X(\omega) = \sup\{y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega\}$ is a random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, quantile

Let F be a distribution function. On $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)=((0,1), \mathfrak{B}(0,1),\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

Define $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by $X(\omega) = \sup\{y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega\}$.

1 Show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (\omega: X(\omega) \leq x) = (\omega: \omega \leq F(x))$

2 Show that X is a RV in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$ and that $F_X = F$.

1 LHS = $(\omega: X(\omega) \leq x)$

= $(\omega: X(\omega) \in (-\infty, x])$

= $(\omega: \sup(y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) < \omega) \in (\infty, x])$

RHS = $(\omega: \omega \leq F(x))$

= $(\omega: \omega \in (-\infty, F(x)])$

= $(\omega: \omega \in (-\infty, P(X^{-1}( \ (-\infty,x] \ ))))$

= $(\omega: \omega \in (-\infty, P(LHS)))$

I'm stuck. Help please? :(

Cross posted : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110704/let-f-be-a-distribution-function-prove-that-x-is-a-rv

Comment: A *distribution function* is in principle a function on $\mathbb R$, or more general on $\mathbb R^n$. A measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ will induce a distribution function $F_X$.

Comment: You should start here just with: 'Let $F$ be a distribution function.' Not a distribution function on $(\Omega,...)$.

Comment: @drhab 1 Edited 3rd statement. sorry for confusion. 2 Do you mean that the existence of a distribution function implies the existence of a random variable inducing it? I think this is precisely what is being attempted to be shown.

Comment: @drhab I edited exactly as it was given to me. "Let F...function. On...measure." The second statement "On...measure." is a fragment.

Comment: To be shown is: if $F$ is some distribution function, then we can always construct some rv $X$ such that its distribution function $F_X$ will satisfy $F_X=F$. A start has been made with this construction and you are asked to prove that the constructed $X$ here satisfies this condition.

Comment: @drhab For the 1st part of 2, does it follow from the fact that X−1(sup(y∈R:F(y)<ω))∈F and the fact that sup(y∈R:F(y)<ω)∈B? No idea for the 2nd part really. Help please? :( And for 1 too?

Comment: Why the cross posting?

Comment: @Did To get more viewers?

Comment: ?? You might be interested to learn that this is contrary to the site's instructions.

Comment: @did Ummmmm why?

Comment: Ummmmm isn't this obvious?

Comment: @Did It is not obvious to me. I read somewhere that it is okay if I mention that I crossposted, but it is discouraged as well.

Comment: In other words you are perfectly aware that it is discouraged but you know better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\left(\omega\right)\leq x<z$ then if follows immediately from
the definition $X\left(\omega\right):=\sup\left\{ y\mid F\left(y\right)<\omega\right\} $
that $F\left(z\right)\geq\omega$.

The fact that $F$ is continuous on the right
then allows the conclusion that also $F\left(x\right)=\lim_{z\rightarrow x+}F\left(z\right)\geq\omega$.

In conversely $F\left(x\right)\geq\omega$ then $X\left(\omega\right)=\sup\left\{ y\mid F\left(y\right)<\omega\right\} \leq x$
because $F$ is non-decreasing.

Proved is now that $$X\left(\omega\right)\leq x\iff\omega\leq F\left(x\right)$$

This equation gives us the second part:

$X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function and this
with: $$F_{X}\left(x\right)=P\left\{ \omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)\leq x\right\} =\lambda\left\{ \omega\in\left(0,1\right)\mid\omega\leq F\left(x\right)\right\} =\lambda\left((0,F\left(x\right)]\right)=F\left(x\right)$$

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Question on last line: Why is it $F(x)]$ and not $F(x))$ ? I was thinking that there was a possibility that $F(x)=1$ so we would have to exclude it. I know it does not matter for Lebesgue measure so the answer is the same regardless. I was just thinking that the LHS of the last inequality should be piecewise or something: ] if $F(x) < 1$ and ) if $F(x) \leq 1$

Comment: Mwah.. I think that $\Omega=\left(0,1\right)$ is a somewhat stupid choice here. To avoid
confusion on this it is better to choose for $\Omega=\left[0,1\right]$.
Then everythings goes fine too and issues like you mention do not arise.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask my prof. Fingers crossed figuring that out isn't part of the homework. If it is though...piecewise then?

Comment: If you wish, but I wouldn't choose for that. Elegance is lost. You
can also it do with a last line that simply leaves out $=\lambda\left((0,F\left(x\right)]\right)$.
Then the disputable interval $(0,F\left(x\right)]$ is kept out of
sight.